# Datastax Cassandra driver 4.x mapper problem with UDT

Tags: java, cassandra, annotations, driver, datastax

I managed to migrate the project's code from driver version 3.x to 4.x using the mapper annotations.

However when process initializes the DAOs I get the error below.

It seems that the annotation processing auto generated code is expecting to locate the Campaign UDT fields as Profile entity columns.

```
2021-11-21 10:41:53,805 [localhost-startStop-1] FATAL esEngine.ProfilesEngineServlet  - ProfilesEngineServlet Failed to init due to exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The CQL ks.table: proj.profile has missing columns: [partner_id, campaign_id] that are defined in the entity class: com.proj.bean.Campaign
        at com.proj.bean.CampaignHelper__MapperGenerated.validateEntityFields(CampaignHelper__MapperGenerated.java:199)
        at com.proj.cql3client.daoimpl.ProfileAccessorImpl__MapperGenerated.initAsync(ProfileAccessorImpl__MapperGenerated.java:1216)
        at com.proj.cql3client.daoimpl.ProfileAccessorImpl__MapperGenerated.init(ProfileAccessorImpl__MapperGenerated.java:1710)
        at com.proj.cql3client.MainDaoMapperImpl__MapperGenerated.lambda$profileAccessor$28(MainDaoMapperImpl__MapperGenerated.java:241)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at com.proj.cql3client.MainDaoMapperImpl__MapperGenerated.profileAccessor(MainDaoMapperImpl__MapperGenerated.java:241)
        at com.proj.cql3client.daoimpl.ProfileDao.<init>(ProfileDao.java:67)
```

I have a profile entity containing a list of campaigns:

```
@Entity
@CqlName ("profile")
public class Profile {
   ...
   @CqlName("campaigns")
   private List<Campaign> campaigns;
   ...
}
```

Campaign is a user defined type:

```
@Entity
@CqlName ("campaign")
public class Campaign {
    ...
    @CqlName("partner_id")
    private int partnerId;
 
    @CqlName("campaign_id")
    private int campaignId;
    ...
}
```

In cassandra campaign type is defined:

```
CREATE TYPE campaign (
    partner_id int,
    campaign_id int
);
```

and the profile table is defined:

```
CREATE TABLE profile (
    ...
    campaigns list<frozen<campaign>>,
    ...
)
```

Registering a codec didn't solve the problem.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Shai

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. In my case the UDT is not in a collection, it's the partition key for a table. The error looks the same though.

The weird thing is that it works fine for some UDTs, but not for others. And I haven't figured out why...